# Doubt regarding proving analyticity of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analyticity, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

I am self studying concepts of complex analysis from Ponnusamy and Silvermann "Complex Variables with Applications"

In the chapter of analytic continuation in basic concepts  authors mention that
the power series $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0 }^ {\infty }  z^n $ converges for $|z|<1$, and hence $f(z)$ is analytic in the disk $|z|<1$ and represents the function $f(z) =\frac1{(1-z)}$.

> I have doubt in this line which follows just after this paragraph- Although power series diverges at each point on $|z|=1$, $f(z)$ is analytic in whole of complex plane except $1$.
>
> As power series converges in  $|z|<1$, so the function $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<1$. But my doubt is how $f(z)$ is analytic for whole of  complex plane except $1$. The limit of derivative would be unbounded if $z>1$. Also $f(z) \neq \frac1{(1-z)}$. So, I cannot differenciate $\frac1{1-z}$ in any neighborhood of point I want to integrate if point is $|z|>1$.

So how $f(z)$ is analytic for whole complex plane except $1$.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: There is something else going on, called "analytic continuation", that has to do with this issue.

Comment: @kimchi lover yes I am studying that part. Can you please explain. I thought proving it doesn't need analytic continuation. It's given in basics of Chapter analytic continuation

Comment: The functions $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ and $\frac{1}{1-z}$ are two different functions, which coincide on $|z|<1$. That's all it means. For any $a\neq1$ the function $\frac{1}{1-z}$ also coincides with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-a)^n}{(1-a)^{n+1}}$, but in the disc with center $a$ and radius $|a-1|$.

Comment: The existence of all those power series converging and coinciding with $1/(1-z)$ on discs around all points $\neq1$ is what tells that $1/(1-z)$ is analytic at all those points.